# Go Resizing Images

Tags: image-processing, go

I am using the Go resize package here: https://github.com/nfnt/resize

1. I am pulling an Image from S3, as such:

   ```
   image_data, err := mybucket.Get(key)
   // this gives me data []byte
   ```
2. After that, I need to resize the image:

   ```
   new_image := resize.Resize(160, 0, original_image, resize.Lanczos3)
   // problem is that the original_image has to be of type image.Image
   ```
3. Upload the image to my S3 bucket

   ```
   err : = mybucket.Put('newpath', new_image, 'image/jpg', 'aclstring')
   // problem is that new image needs to be data []byte
   ```

How do I transform a data `[]byte` to ---> `image.Image` and back to ----> data `[]byte`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Read http://golang.org/pkg/image

```
// you need the image package, and a format package for encoding/decoding
import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg" // if you don't need to use jpeg.Encode, use this line instead 
    // _ "image/jpeg"

    "github.com/nfnt/resize"

    
)

// Decoding gives you an Image.
// If you have an io.Reader already, you can give that to Decode 
// without reading it into a []byte.
image, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
// check err

newImage := resize.Resize(160, 0, original_image, resize.Lanczos3)

// Encode uses a Writer, use a Buffer if you need the raw []byte
err = jpeg.Encode(someWriter, newImage, nil)
// check err
```

Comment: Awesome. What is the underscore before "image/jpeg" for? Also how is the bytes variable available to me? Lastly, how do I encode back into []byte? Thanks so much

Comment: The underscore is how you import something only for it's side effects (registering the decoder in this case). Import without the underscore to use `jpeg.Encode`. `bytes` is a package in the standard library.

Comment: If you know that the input image is jpeg, you can do `jpeg.Decode` (instead of `image.Decode`)

Comment: From where are you importing this `resize` package?

Comment: I see a lot of people recommending this library specifically, but I just checked it and it is no longer being supported. You may want to look for another option such as @Inkeliz answer.

Answer (score 50):

The OP is using a specific library/package, but I think that the issue of "Go Resizing Images" can be solved without that package.

You can resize de image using `golang.org/x/image/draw`:

```
input, _ := os.Open("your_image.png")
defer input.Close()

output, _ := os.Create("your_image_resized.png")
defer output.Close()

// Decode the image (from PNG to image.Image):
src, _ := png.Decode(input)

// Set the expected size that you want:
dst := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, src.Bounds().Max.X/2, src.Bounds().Max.Y/2))

// Resize:
draw.NearestNeighbor.Scale(dst, dst.Rect, src, src.Bounds(), draw.Over, nil)

// Encode to `output`:      
png.Encode(output, dst)
```

In that case I choose `draw.NearestNeighbor`, because it's faster, but looks worse. but there's other methods, you can see on https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image/draw#pkg-variables:

- `draw.NearestNeighbor`
  NearestNeighbor is the nearest neighbor interpolator. It is very fast, but usually gives very low quality results. When scaling up, the result  will look 'blocky'.
- `draw.ApproxBiLinear`
  ApproxBiLinear is a mixture of the nearest neighbor and bi-linear interpolators. It is fast, but usually gives medium quality results.
- `draw.BiLinear`
  BiLinear is the tent kernel. It is slow, but usually gives high quality results.
- `draw.CatmullRom`
  CatmullRom is the Catmull-Rom kernel. It is very slow, but usually gives very high quality results.

Answer (score 9):

Want to do it [29 times faster](https://github.com/fawick/speedtest-resize)? Try amazing [`vipsthumbnail`](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Libvips) instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libvips-tools
vipsthumbnail --help-all
```

This will resize and nicely crop saving result to a file:

```
vipsthumbnail original.jpg -s 700x200 -o 700x200.jpg -c
```

Calling from Go:

```
func resizeExternally(from string, to string, width uint, height uint) error {
    var args = []string{
        "--size", strconv.FormatUint(uint64(width), 10) + "x" +
            strconv.FormatUint(uint64(height), 10),
        "--output", to,
        "--crop",
        from,
    }
    path, err := exec.LookPath("vipsthumbnail")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(path, args...)
    return cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: In cases where system calls are undesirable, there is a [binding](https://github.com/DAddYE/vips) too.

Comment: It is useful to observe that you use portability with this approach. Using pure Go gives you portability for every OS/arch that Go supports.

Comment: @joonas.fi , is this library recommended, then?

Comment: @gbenroscience oops I had a typo, I meant to say "lose portability". I meant that since it's calling an external program, your Go program isn't self contained and as portable as pure go can offer you. The code in the accepted answer is better in this respect.

Comment: How is this answer related to the original question?

Comment: Instead of using Libvips like this, I recommend using https://github.com/davidbyttow/govips which is a golang wrapper over Libvips.

Comment: It is nicer than calling an external process, but it still requires you to have this lib installed on your OS, which makes the code not portable/self contained

Answer (score 4):

You could use [bimg](https://github.com/h2non/bimg), which is powered by [libvips](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips) (a fast image processing library written in C).

If you are looking for a image resizing solution as a service, take a look to [imaginary](https://github.com/h2non/imaginary)

Answer (score 0):

No third party package. The following code can reduce the image size to minimum 50px height.

```
func resizeImage(img image.RGBA, height int) image.RGBA {
    if height < 50 {
        return img
    }
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    imgHeight := bounds.Dy()
    if height >= imgHeight {
        return img
    }
    imgWidth := bounds.Dx()
    resizeFactor := float32(imgHeight) / float32(height)
    ratio := float32(imgWidth) / float32(imgHeight)
    width := int(float32(height) * ratio)
    resizedImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height))
    var imgX, imgY int
    var imgColor color.Color
    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
            imgX = int(resizeFactor*float32(x) + 0.5)
            imgY = int(resizeFactor*float32(y) + 0.5)
            imgColor = img.At(imgX, imgY)
            resizedImage.Set(x, y, imgColor)
        }
    }
    return *resizedImage
}
```