# how to use golang compress and resize a gif

Tags: go, image-processing, gif

Is there has method or lib to compress and resize a gif use golang?

ps: I was tried **[bimg](https://github.com/h2non/bimg)**, but it not support gif.

Comment: bimg uses libvips via C-bindings. Does your  lipvbs builded with gif support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see doc https://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#GIF

```
func DecodeAll(r io.Reader) (*GIF, error)
```

now you can get a GIF struct

```
type GIF struct {
        Image []*image.Paletted // The successive images.
```

then you can resize each of Image in GIF.

```
for _,img:=range gif.Image{
    resize(img)
}
```

PS: image.Paletted implemented image.Image, so you can use https://github.com/nfnt/resize to resize the Image.

Comment: `resize` only supports resize a image, does not support compression

Comment: image.Image is an interface (`https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image`). And image.Paletted implemented that interface. Check `https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Paletted`.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used but I think you can read/write GIFs using the std library (import "image/gif"). Then resize using something like "resize" (see [Go Resizing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940724/go-resizing-images))